# A chrome extension with Python Flask + Ajax call

Tags: javascript, python

I'm building a chrome extension where upon clicking a button, a python script will execute and will send back the output to the javascript chrome extension through an ajax call and a python server flask communication.

[Here is the error on python flask server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmbfO.png)
[Here is the error on the console of the website i'm adding a chrome extension to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yjC3.png)

Here is my python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

@app.route('/_get_data/', methods=['POST'])
def _get_data():
    myList = ['Element1', 'Element2', 'Element3']
    return jsonify({'data' : myList})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Then to my chrome extension code:

Manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "TagRecom",
    "description": "Tag Recommendation System for Stack Overflow",
    "version": "1.0",

    "background": {
        "scripts" : ["background.js"],
        "persistent" : false
    },
    "content_scripts" : [
        {
            "matches" : ["https://stackoverflow.com/questions/*"],
            "js": ["jquery.js", "require.js","contentScript.js"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ],
    "permissions" : [
        "https://stackoverflow.com/", "tabs", "activeTab", "storage" 
    ]
}
```

ContentScript.js:

```
var tagrecom_btn = document.createElement('a');
tagrecom_btn.id = "tagrecom_btn";
tagrecom_btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Tag Suggestions"));


document.getElementById('tagrecom_btn').onclick = function(){
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({message: "listeners"}, function(response) {
    });
}
```

Background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log("Entered");
        if (request.message == "listeners") {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "injectedScript.js"});   
        }
    }
);
```

And finally the injectedScript.js:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/_get_data/",
    type: "POST",
    success: function(resp){
      console.log(resp);
    },
    error: function(e, s, t) {
      console.log("ERROR OCCURRED");
      console.log(e);
      console.log(s);
      console.log(t);
    }
});
```

Please i really need your help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add your server to the permissions and it will work

I was using my local server flask backend, so my manifest.json will contain

"permissions": ["http://localhost/*"],